# Show item from specific subsite level in page layout

Tags: page-layout

I'm using a page layout to style some content pages on my Sharepoint 2010 public facing website.
On this specific page layout I need to add something which is only visible from the third level of subsites, this meaning this level: http://www.website.com/subsite1/subsubsite1/pages/default.aspx

When a user is on this level, sitename subsubsite1, he/she needs to see a server control.
Is there a way I can do such a thing, without needing to code something. I create a webpart which could do such a thing, but that's not a preferred option.

I'll try to make this a bit more concrete with an example.
The thing I need to add is an asp:Repeater which contains several menu items of the next level of subsites. The reason we use an asp:Repeater for it is because the default sharepoint:Menu screws up our html (there'a a table wrapper around the menu), also we've got a bit more control on the created html when using this repeater.

The page layout looks like this:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div id="left_content_container_big" class="global_settings_containers">
        <div id="top_shadow" class="global_settings_containers">
        </div>
        <div id="middle_shadow" class="global_settings_containers">
            <div id="left_content_big">             
                <div class="left_content_big_menu">
                    <div id="sub_submenu" class="">
                        <asp:Repeater ID="SubMenuLevel3" runat="server" DataSourceID="cjgSiteMapLevel3">
                            <HeaderTemplate><ul id="sub_submenu_ul" class=""></HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate><li><a href="<%# Eval("Url")%>" class="" >
                                                <%# Eval("Title")%></a></li></ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate></ul></FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater>
                    </div>
                    <asp:SiteMapDataSource
                        ShowStartingNode="false"
                        SiteMapProvider="CurrentNavSiteMapProvider"
                        EnableViewState="true"
                        StartFromCurrentNode="false"
                        StartingNodeOffset="2"
                        id="cjgSiteMapLevel3"
                        runat="server"/>
                </div>
                <div id="left_content_big_cnt">
                    <div class="PageTitle">
                        <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue id="PageTitle2" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
                    </div>
                    <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
                    <WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager runat="server" id="spproxywebpartmanager"></WebPartPages:SPProxyWebPartManager>
                        <WebPartPages:WebPartZone id="WPZone_Main" runat="server" title="Main"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom_shadow" class="global_settings_containers">
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Now all I need to do is add something to the repeater so it's only shown from the third level.
Using a different page layout could be an option, but just as creating a webpart, not really preferred.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

*Answer edited into question by OP:*

I fixed my problem with a bit of javascript. Not a very good solution, but it solves the problem for now. As Sharepoint doesn't work properly itself when javascript is disabled, it's not really an issue.
The code used is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var segments = 0;
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        segments = path.split('/').length;
        //Hide the menu if we aren't 3 levels deep in the site.
        if( segments < 5 )
        {
            jQuery(".left_content_big_menu").hide();
        }
    </script>
```